# Как стилизовать кнопку включения видео?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу стилизовать кнопку включения видео, например, как показано на картинке? Или придётся писать собственный плеер, чтобы изменить одну маленькую деталь?

Comment: Вы можете оставить дефолтные контролс, но на центральную кнопку наложить абсолютным позиционированием свою, а в обработчик клика привязать `<some video player>.play()/pause()  (в зависимости от того, воспроизводится ли сейчас видео)` Эту кнопку отображать/скрывать по отображении/скрытии контролсов (события видеоплеера `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`)

Comment: @artomich большое спасибо)